# AVFoundation NSURL not displaying correcty?

Tags: objective-c, ios

So I am trying to livestream a video using the http live stream example apple provides. The program compiles but, it wont display anything on my iphone. Below is the code:

Thank you.

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<#http://developer.apple.com/resources/http-streaming/examples/advanced-stream.html#>"];
    /*
     // You may find a test stream at <http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8>.
     self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
     [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];
     self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
  */
    /*

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&PlayerStatusContext];
    */

                  self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

                  //(optional) [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];

                  self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

                  self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

    [player play];
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this apple sample code. this is using a AVFoundation.

I look at the following Apple's sample code is recommended.

You just want to implement the steps in it seems to be under the code You will be very helpful.

[StitchedStreamPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092)

I upload to myServer Tested. Perfectly. also Youtube, Vimeo and so on... is work fine.

Trust me. 3G, wifi tested in both environments. although sample code, It was surprisingly works perfectly.

Comment: how can i make it autoplay? sorry im a noob. =/

Comment: I tried youtube, vimeo and many others and it throw an error: "Unknown error: -12939". Am I missing something?? Could someone help with this issue?

Comment: This isn't allowed to use with Youtube as it's against their TOS, it works yes, but you're not allowed to play any youtube content except through the Youtube player.

Source: http://youtube.com/terms